# Show hidden worksheet on icon click

Tags: excel

I have a workbook which has an org chart on one of the worksheets.

Further hidden worksheets have been loaded with the job spec for each of the job roles.

I would like to be able to click on the job role in the org chart and have it show the relevant hidden worksheet for that role.

There should also be a home icon which takes the user back to the org chart and hides the worksheet that they came from once again.

I would like this to be the case for all job roles listed in the org chart where a user can click on any job role and it opens the relevant job specification worksheet.

Comment: This should get you started. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True. Change True to False when you want the sheet to be hidden.

Comment: Sheets("YourNameHere").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden and then Sheets("YourNameHere").Visible = xlSheetVisible

Comment: Do I put this on the command button on the org chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way (there are many ways to do this):

**Insert the buttons** you need on your Org Chart (Developer>Insert>Form Controls>Button). You will need to create a button on each org sheet as well to return you back to your org sheet.

**Paste the below code in a module**

**Modify to fit your workbook**
(change sheet names to your sheets). The `Sub Home()` will take you back to your main org chart.

```
Sub Agents()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Agents").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Agents").Activate
End Sub

Sub TeamLeads()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Team Leads").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Team Leads").Activate
End Sub

Sub Managers()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Managers").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Managers").Activate
End Sub

Sub Home()
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Org").Activate
End Sub
```

**Assign each macro to the corresponding button**
 To do this, right click on the button>Assign Macro>Select appropriate macro. All of your "Return to Org Chart" buttons should be assigned to the "Home" macro in this example.

Users will still be able to manually unhide the sheets in excel using the above method. If you do not want that to be an option, you can use the below method to hide/unhide sheets:

> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourNameHere").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
>   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourNameHere").Visible = xlSheetVisible

Comment: Will be having a go in the next hour, will let you know how it goes! Thank you 

Comment: So I have inserted the button and put the code (first paragraph only) and changed Agent to the relevant worksheet anme (GKAM) but keep getting an error. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's OK, I think I've worked it out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Plz mark solution (check box next to above solution)if this post resolved your initial ask. Please not you should create a new question for future issues - do not mod the question as you work through your project :)